Trying to execute a simple stored procedure - Help! Can't find an answer that works here
I'm completely new to SQL and am trying to execute a stored procedure that I'm not even sure I wrote correctly. It's supposed to give the total number of patients for a given dr, and this is the stored procedure I managed to compile in Oracle SQL Developer:
CREATE PROCEDURE Totalptcount
    (drid IN INTEGER,
     totalpts OUT INTEGER)
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(pts) AS totalpts
    INTO totalpts
    FROM ptlist
    WHERE drid = '1';
END Totalptcount;

I'm trying to input the value '1' and get out the total pt count (row count) for dr w/the ID '1'.
How do I execute this? Thanks so much in advance
Tried a number of answers I found here for similar questions but none worked. I also don't know how to use cursors or declare but I don't think they'd be needed for my stored procedure (I think). I've tried:
var totalpts NUMBER
EXEC totalptcount (:totalpts);
SELECT totalpts; 
- This gave the INTO clause requirement error

BEGIN
    Exec totalptcount
END; 
- I don't really know what I'm doing and just tried this

BEGIN
    Exec totalptcount('1')
END;
- Trying to input value '1' to get out the count
- Unknown command error

Thank you in advance!

Exec is a SQL*\Plus command that cannot be used in a PL/SQL block. The procedure Totalptcount must be called with both arguments, one of which must be a variable. Any single statement inside a PL/SQL block must end with a semicolon. Until version 23, a SELECT statement must have a FROM clause, such as SELECT * FROM DUAL;. You might want to look at a tutorial for more help getting started, Stack Overflow likely isn't the place to help you get started on this project.

Calling a stored procedure (named PL/SQL unit) is done within another PL/SQL block. SQL*Plus however has a shortcut, EXEC which simply wraps the command in a PL/SQL BEGIN .... END; wrapper. You can retrieve the value into a bind variable or a local PL/SQL variable and print it to your display in various ways:
In SQL*Plus:
var totalpts NUMBER

EXEC Totalptcount(1,:totalpts);

print totalpts

Or
var totalpts NUMBER

BEGIN
  Totalptcount(1,:totalpts);
END;

print totalpts

Or:
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE
  totalpts number;
BEGIN
  Totalptcount(1,totalpts);
  dbms_output.put_line(totalpts);
END;

Or even:
var totalpts NUMBER

DECLARE
  totalpts number;
BEGIN
  Totalptcount(1,var_totalpts);
  :totalpts  := var_totalpts;
END;

print totalpts

Lots of options, and this is just for SQLPlus client. How you call a procedure and retrieve the result depends on the client technology stack you are using (in this case, SQLPlus, but it could be many things).
Keep in mind, however, that for most basic SQL needs, you don't need procedures at all. Simply write SQL that obtains the result you need and execute it directly. We use PL/SQL when we have more complex needs that require full programmatic flow control that SQL by itself doesn't provide.

Thank you!! Both for the suggestions and the other info. I definitely need to do more reading. I did this to just learn about procedures in general but that makes a lot of sense that it wouldn't be used for such simple tasks. I really appreciate your help!

After your compile it, go into the connections window.
Open the schema.
One of the folders there should be for procedures.
Find your procedure and open it..
You should see a tool which is a green triangle.
Click that and it will open a dialog that can be used to run your procedure.

You may find some reading on https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/ may help shorten your learning curve.
I suggest your rename your drid parameter to input_drid, and use it to replace the hardcoded '1'  in your query.  That way you can pick any dr id you want.

Thank you!! I will check that site out, and thanks for the tip about renaming it and the directions for finding that dialog. I saw some screenshots with it but I had no idea how to get there. I also was lost on how to make it work for any dr id, so thanks so much!
